# Autoplay slider with javascript

Tags: javascript, slider, autoplay

im asked to make a autoplay slider but after learning javascript ... i still have no clue how to apply what i've learned ... Need some help ..

Im asked to make an autoplay slider which changes slides every 5s ...

I builded my slider with inputs which shows the checked input in the middle but no clue how to make it work with js..

what i want to do with javascript : when "input" is checked => wait 5s and next input is checked and so on ....

I also need to be able to stop the autoplay when i click on the slider / and be able to switch slides with the keyboard's arrows ...

Here's my HTML

```
<section id="slider">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
    <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">
    <label for="s1" id="slide1">Slide 1</label>
    <label for="s2" id="slide2">Slide 2</label>
    <label for="s3" id="slide3">Slide 3</label>
    <label for="s4" id="slide4">Slide 4</label>
    <label for="s5" id="slide5">Slide 5</label>

Here's my CSS 

* {
}

body {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 40rem;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.9s ease;
}
/* far left*/
#s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
#s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(-65%,0,-200px) rotateY(10deg);
}
/* left */
#s1:checked ~ #slide5, #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
#s3:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
#s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(-25%,0,-100px) rotateY(10deg);
}
/* middle */
#s1:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide3, #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
#s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0px 30px 80px -9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
/* right */
#s1:checked ~ #slide2, #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
#s3:checked ~ #slide4, #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
#s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(25%,0,-100px) rotateY(-10deg);
}
/* far right */
#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
#s3:checked ~ #slide5, #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
#s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(65%,0,-200px) rotateY(-10deg);
}

/*slide content*/
#slide1 { background: #00bcd4 }
#slide2 { background: #4caf50 }
#slide3 { background: #6a4caf }
#slide4 { background: #ffc107 }
#slide5 { background: #ff5722 }

#slide1, #slide2, #slide3, #slide4, #slide5 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Lookup "JavaScript Events". Create a function for each event: input.click, slider.click, left-arrow.pressed, right-arrow.pressed. Lastly, to automatically make slider transition from one slide to the next, you will need to use setInterval() to make the slide transition. Then use clearInterval() to kill the job setInterval() started (stopping rotation). jQuery would make all of this an easy task; but if you're determined to do this with pure JavaScript, check out some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130851/implement-plain-javascript-carousel-without-plugin

Answer (score -1):

Check w3 slideshow https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp That maybe help you.